# left-right scroll icon appears randomly and disables scrolling in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

[image]

The icon above shows up randomly in my Windows 8 and disables scrolling for me. It looks like the option for left-right click with scroll, which my mouse doesn't have. I don't know how this option called so I can't do successful search.

I didn't install any software for a different mouse that may have this option.
And the biggest mystery is that is shows up completely random, to make it disappear I have to alt-tab few times.

How do I disable this?

Comment: Even if you mouse doesn't have a tilt-wheel doesn't mean it doesn't support horizontal scrolling by say holding the middle button. Maybe you have a faulty/hair-trigger button. Try a different mouse to determine if it's the mouse itself.

Comment: After checking everything again and searching for A4 tech weird scroll i came to conclusion that my A4 tech drivers have this weird option turned on even though i don't have side scrolling on my mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the software go to 4-wheel settings and turn off 4-wheel scroll like in picture and it solves the problem.

[image: a4tech software control]

Comment: works! in order to get there, right click system icon, and go to "4-way wheel settings"